# Apple tv (3rd Gen): display album covers immediately

Tags: appletv, airplay

I've recently started using an Apple TV 3rd gen. It's mainly a way to broadcast Spotify and Netflix from my phone. One thing that is starting to bug me a bit is the fact that, when I start playing a song via Airplay, it takes several minutes for the Apple TV to switch from the homescreen to full-screen album cover display.

I'd prefer for it to switch to that immediately. Alternatively, I wouldn't mind pressing some key combination on the remote, or for it to switch to an all-black screen instead. The main point is that I don't want to stare at the homescreen with all it's colourful apps and 'Top movies' for several minutes.

Is there a way to configure this behaviour?

Comment: Turn the screensaver start value down as low as it will go.  I'm not sure that solves your problem, but ours is configured with photo's as the screensaver and I'm guessing that's what your album covers are, the screensaver.

Comment: Nope. That's what I tried initially, but all I got was that photo stream; there's option for e.g. an all-black screen. The album covers I was refering to are basically the 'now playing'-screen, which also displays the song title and the 'progress'.